# Get Facebook Friend List in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Facebook friend list with name, id, etc in my app.

```
- (IBAction)onFBLogin:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"%@", result);
             [self getFBEmailAddress];
        }
     }];
}
-(void)getFBEmailAddress{
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                       parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, email, friends"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSString *pictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"picture"]];
             mFBId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
             NSLog(@"My Profile : %@", result);
             NSLog(@"email is %@", [result objectForKey:@"email"]);

             [self getFBFriendList];
         }
         else{
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
}
-(void)getFBFriendList{

    NSString* graphPat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/friends", mFBId];

    FBSDKGraphRequest *requestFriends = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                         initWithGraphPath:graphPat
                                         parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name"}
                                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [requestFriends startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
        if (!error && result)
        {
            NSArray *allFriendsResultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

            if ([allFriendsResultData count] > 0)
            {
                for (NSDictionary *friendObject in allFriendsResultData)
                {
                    NSString *friendName = [friendObject objectForKey:@"name"];
                    NSString *friendID = [friendObject objectForKey:@"id"];
                    NSLog(@"%@ : %@", friendID, friendName);

                }
            }
        }

    }];}
```

I've succeed to login via Facebook and get my profile. After that, I've tried to get friend list via the friends graph api. But at that time, it only said count of friends following as below.

```
    friends =     {
        data =         (
        );
        summary =         {
            "total_count" = 2;
        };
    };
    id = 60XXXXXX1295X;
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1..._501957533...";
        };
    };
```

How Can I get full information of friends list such as id, name, etc? Please help me if any one already implemented. Thank you.

Comment: Please give me answer how to solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me.

```
NSMutableArray *completeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self fetchFacebookEachFriend:completeList withGrapPath:@"/me/friends" withCallback:^(BOOL success, NSMutableArray * fbList) {
     //Finish get All Friends
     fbListFinal(success, fbList);
}];


- (void)fetchFacebookEachFriend:(NSMutableArray *)completeList withGrapPath:(NSString *)graphPath withCallback:(returnFbList)fbList
{
    NSDictionary *limitDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email", @"fields", nil];
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:limitDictionary HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Please connect to Facebook to find your friends" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
            fbList(NO, completeList);
            return;
        }

        //Add each friend to list
        for (NSDictionary *friend in [result valueForKey:@"data"]) {
            [completeList addObject:friend];
        }

        if ([result valueForKey:@"paging"] != nil && [[result valueForKey:@"paging"] valueForKey:@"next"] != nil) {
            NSString *nextPage = [[result valueForKey:@"paging"] valueForKey:@"next"];
            nextPage = [[nextPage componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"] objectAtIndex:1];
            [self fetchFacebookEachFriend:completeList withGrapPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/friends?%@",nextPage] withCallback:fbList];
        } else
            fbList(YES, completeList);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`result.paging.next` contains the complete URL, with access token and all. I find the simplest thing is just to pass it on to an `NSURLSession` data task:

```
NSString *nextPage = result[@"paging"][@"next"];
if (!nextPage) return;
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nextPage] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    id json = [self decodeJSONResult:data response:response error:error];
    // use json
}] resume];
```

I wrote this as an `FBSDKGraphRequest` extension: [FBSDKGraphRequest+Paging.h](https://gist.github.com/yonat/0a37ccb89adfc8f92d740e8549093d14)